# 2sxc dnn edit app not working in IE 11

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

So My Problem is when using 2sxc app edit from dnn edit page hover menu, In IE it is not working and showing error

```
    SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'
File: inpage.min.js, Line: 1, Column: 12721
```

which was coming from some inpage.min.js loaded from installed 2sxc desktop module and this `inpage.min.js` was not re-loading as its status code when checked in network traffic

`Key    Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified`

which obviously means it will not re-load the js (inpage.min.js) again as it is not modified

so  it would be very helpful if somebody can solve this why it is not opening normal dnn edit popup through edit page hover menu edit app.??

After upgrading to 2sxc 9.23 i am still getting error as

```
    promise of undefined
```

[ScreenShot of Error](https://i.imgur.com/LC4SHcY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which version of 2sxc you are using.  A couple of recent releases had an issue with those controls.  I think that these have been repaired in 9.23.  You might want to upgrade to that version of the module.

Comment: we are using [2sxc 9.14 LTS](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/releases/tag/v09.14.00) and we are using LTS Latest release and v09.23.00 is a Pre-release is it usable is production site and if not what is prospective date of getting next LTS latest release.?

Comment: after upgrading to [2sxc 9.23](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/releases/tag/v09.23.00) still giving
    SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined
    File: inpage.min.js, Line: 1, Column: 34068

Comment: and this is the only critical issue we are facing now.

Comment: What is that js file?  Is it part of 2sxc or something else?

Comment: thanks Joe, Yes it is part of 2sxc module which gets install with its install package in path ..\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\dist\inpage\ folder

Comment: after doing some research digging i found Promise is coming undefined as it is not supported in IE, So its Polyfill must be provided.

Comment: can you please suggest how we should proceed.!!

Comment: @Mickers can you reply on this

Comment: just fyi: it seems to be fixed in 9.30. Please wait for 9.31 though, because there is still a fairly large bug we want to fix.